# Cumulative sum and cumulative count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying establish treatment courses for patients, below is sample table I am working on.

| PatientID | SessionDate | Next_date | diff | courses | Coursenum | course_Count | Total Sesion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 12/13/2012 | NULL | 1.1 | start | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/14/2012 | 12/13/2012 | 1 | existing | 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/14/2012 | 12/14/2012 | 0 | existing | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/17/2012 | 12/14/2012 | 3 | existing | 1 | 4 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/18/2012 | 12/17/2012 | 1 | existing | 1 | 5 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/19/2012 | 12/18/2012 | 1 | existing | 1 | 6 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/21/2012 | 12/19/2012 | 2 | existing | 1 | 7 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/21/2012 | 12/21/2012 | 0 | existing | 1 | 8 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/22/2012 | 12/21/2012 | 1 | existing | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 10000 | 12/24/2012 | 12/22/2012 | 2 | existing | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 10000 | 9/17/2015 | 1/25/2013 | 965 | start | 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/18/2015 | 9/17/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/21/2015 | 9/18/2015 | 3 | existing | 2 | 3 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/22/2015 | 9/21/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 4 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/23/2015 | 9/22/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 5 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/25/2015 | 9/23/2015 | 2 | existing | 2 | 6 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/28/2015 | 9/25/2015 | 3 | existing | 2 | 7 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/29/2015 | 9/28/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 8 | 20 |
| 10000 | 9/30/2015 | 9/29/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 9 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/2/2015 | 9/30/2015 | 2 | existing | 2 | 10 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/5/2015 | 10/2/2015 | 3 | existing | 2 | 11 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/6/2015 | 10/5/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 12 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/7/2015 | 10/6/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 13 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/9/2015 | 10/7/2015 | 2 | existing | 2 | 14 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/12/2015 | 10/9/2015 | 3 | existing | 2 | 15 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/13/2015 | 10/12/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 16 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/14/2015 | 10/13/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 17 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/16/2015 | 10/14/2015 | 2 | existing | 2 | 18 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/19/2015 | 10/16/2015 | 3 | existing | 2 | 19 | 20 |
| 10000 | 10/20/2015 | 10/19/2015 | 1 | existing | 2 | 20 | 20 |

I achieved this output using python

Note: 1.1 in diff column is just a placeholeder for NULL

sessions['Coursenum']=(sessions.status.eq('start')).cumsum()
sessions['course_count']=sessions.groupby(['Coursenum']).cumcount()+1
sessions['TotalSessions']=sessions.groupby('Coursenum')['course_count'].transform('max')

I wanted to program this using sql. Is there a way to do this in sql?

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? Are you using MySQL 8.0? This task can be done most effectively using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: @BillKarwin I am using MS sql server 2016. Apologies for including mysql tag wrongly.

Comment: Okay, I have removed the mysql tag. I don't use SQL Server, but window functions should work similarly. I can't test it, so I'll leave it to someone else to develop an answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank You for the head start. I am experimenting with RowNumber() function

Comment: I was thinking of something like `SUM(CASE courses WHEN 'start' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY SessionDate) AS CourseNum`

Comment: Don't get what you try to achieve, could you please provide your schema, and additional details on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use window functions in SQL whenever we want to show group-level aggregations in raw data itself.

```
select *, max(course_Count) over (partition by Coursenum order by Session_date) as Total_Session 
from( select *, count(*) over (partition by Coursenum order by Session_date) as course_Count 
from( select *,sum(case when courses = 'start' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by Session_date) as Coursenum
from [table_name]
) A)
```

Refer [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-functions-in-sql/) for more information on window functions
and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-case-statement/) for Case statement

Answer (score 2):

I think window functions using count() and sum() would work here with the proper order by.

`select count(coursenum) over (partition by coursenum order by sessiondate)` should get you cumulative count.